# Parse block name and instanace name from the text with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse following text

```
`ifndef abc
`define abc
module xyz(

block
      #(
        .BLK                            (def::a)
    )
    inst
       (/*AUTOINST*/
```

This is the regex I tried:

```
(\w+)\s*.*?(\w+)\n*\s*\(\n*\/\*AUTOINST\*\/
```

Expected output:

```
Match
1. block
2. inst
```

Actual output:

```
Match
1.  ifndef
2.  inst
```

*Updated*

There are multiple ways to define the same block of code:
How do I parse all the blocks and instances from all these different styles of codes with one regex?
If this is my test input with `(\w+)\s*.*?(\w+)\n*\s*\(\n*\/\*AUTOINST\*\/` regex, then I get 4 out of 5 output correctly.

```
block1
#(.en (en))
inst1
(/*AUTOINST*/

block2 inst2
(
/*AUTOINST*/

block3 inst3
(/*AUTOINST*/

block4
#(.en (en))
inst4(/*AUTOINST*/

block5
      #(
        .BLK                            (defs::blk)
    )
    inst5
       (/*AUTOINST*/
```

output:

```
Match 1
1.  block1
2.  inst1
Match 2
1.  block2
2.  inst2
Match 3
1.  block3
2.  inst3
Match 4
1.  block4
2.  inst4
```

If there is any extra line at the beginning, then first match is incorrect:

```
ifndef abc 

block1
#(.en (en))
inst1
(/*AUTOINST*/
```

output:

```
Match 1
1.  ifndef
2.  inst1
```

Can someone help me figure out what is the issue here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
(\w+)([\r\n]+)
```

Here is a live [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FBMPV4/1)

Comment: It did not work, I get following output:
Match 1
1. abc
2. 
Match 2
1. abc
2. 
Match 3
1. block
2. 
Match 4
1. inst
2.

Comment: Do you apply any cleaning ( removing spaces etc.) process? This one finds them by enter chars. If you do please provide input so.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
^(\w+)(?:\n(?!\s*\w).*)*\n\s*(\w+)\n\s*\(/\*AUTOINST\*/
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars in **group 1**
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n(?!\s*\w).*` Match a newline and assert what after optional whitespace chars there is no word chars
- `)*` Close group and optionally repeat
- `\n\s*` Match a newline and optional whitespace chars
- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars in **group 2**
- `\n\s*` Match a newline and optional whitespace chars
- `\(/\*AUTOINST\*/` Match `(/*AUTOINST*/`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fqPCrW/1) | or a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cYA8EH)

For example, returning the capture group values with [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re

regex = r"^(\w+)(?:\n(?!\s*\w).*)*\n\s*(\w+)\n\s*\(/\*AUTOINST\*/"

s = ("`ifndef abc\n"
    "`define abc\n"
    "module xyz(\n\n"
    "block\n"
    "      #(\n"
    "        .BLK                            (def::a)\n"
    "    )\n"
    "    inst\n"
    "       (/*AUTOINST*/")
    
print(re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
[('block', 'inst')]
```

Comment: I tried this on my full input and sadly it did not work. I have updated my question with the extended input for which I don't get the desired output with your suggested regex.

Comment: @Sweety I don't see an update to the question.

Comment: My bad, forgot to submit the updated changes. I just updated. Thanks!